# Removing nan values from bar graph matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to remove nan values from showing up on the tail end of my bar graph, this is my code reading from a csv stored in `scorecard`

```
errors = scorecard.Errors
y_pos = np.arange(len(errors))
total = scorecard.Total

plt.bar(y_pos, total, align='center')
plt.xticks(y_pos, errors)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

which displays this: [image]

Comment: It would be better if you cleaned the data before plotting the graph using `dropna()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dropna removes more data than I would like.

I tried adding a simple `plt.plot()` at the end of the block at it got rid of the two `nan`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas lib to read the csv, you can use the function `dropna()` like the documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Using like this

`scorecard.dropna()`